# CSS Sprite code works in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-sprites

I wrote simple animation using CSS and HTML using sprites.
It works successful in chrome and IE but not firefox.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #sprite {
    width: 96px;
    height: 117px;
    background: url(../../images/sprite_animation_frames.png) 0px 0px;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body onload="main();">
  <p align="center"><h1>The Running Man</h1></p>
  <script>
  var position = [
    [0,   0],[-100,   0],[-200,   0],[-300,   0],[-400,   0],[-500,   0],
    [0,-120],[-100,-120],[-200,-120],[-300,-120],[-400,-120],[-500,-120],
    [0,-240],[-100,-240],[-200,-240],[-300,-240],[-400,-240],[-500,-240],
    [0,-360],[-100,-360],[-200,-360],[-300,-360],[-400,-360],[-500,-360],
    [0,-480],[-100,-480],[-200,-480],[-300,-480],[-400,-480],[-500,-480]
  ];
  var pos;
  function main(){
    var img = document.createElement('img')
    img.id = 'sprite';
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    setInterval(function () {
      anim(img);
    }, 50);
  }
  var i = 0;
  function anim(el) {
    if (i < 30)
      i++;
    else
      i = 0;
    var x = position[i][0];
    var y = position[i][1];
    el.style.backgroundPositionX = x + 'px ';
    el.style.backgroundPositionY = y + 'px ';
  }
  </script>
```

what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not support individual `backgroundPositionX`/`Y` properties, and IE may be complaining about the extra space. Try:

```
el.style.backgroundPosition = x+"px "+y+"px";
```

Comment: Hi @Niet the Dark Absol
I tried the change you suggested but still same, No image is getting displayed. I done inspect element and observe that img background-position keeps changing but no image is getting displayed.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Is the `background-image` being set properly on the element?

Comment: Hello Neit
I solved the issue, Thanks for your help.
Instead of img tag, I used "div" tag, it worked .. don't know the reason

Answer (score 0):

Able to solve the problem.

Just replaced div tag instead of img and it worked.

Don't know the issue.